# Can't display second of two D3 piecharts in html

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an html page where I want to display 2 piegraphs that were each created via d3. I can display each pie chart individually, however, when I try to display both of them side by side, the second one is blank. The first one comes in fine.

These pie graphs are created via the javascript from:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887235

The main difference is that I have put the javascript in a file and nested it around a function

> function piechart2() { ... }

I can display each piechart on it's own, but I can't seem to display both pie charts side by side.

This works to display pie chart1:

```
    <div class="row">
     <h3 align="center" >Connect</h3>
      <div class="row placeholders">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
          <svg width="300" height="200"></svg>
          <script>piechart()</script>
        </div>
</div>
```

This works to display pie chart2

```
        <div class="row">
     <h3 align="center" >Connect</h3>
      <div class="row placeholders">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
          <svg width="300" height="200"></svg>
          <script>piechart2()</script>
        </div>
</div>
```

However, this only displays piechar1. When you look at the developer tools, you can see that the space where the piechar2 should be is blank.

```
    <div class="row">
     <h3 align="center" >Connect</h3>
      <div class="row placeholders">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
          <svg width="300" height="200"></svg>
          <script>piechart()</script>
          <script>piechart2()</script>
        </div>
</div>
```

In my file's head I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/donut.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/donut2.js"></script>
```

Here's the javascript. The only differences bewteen the two js files are that one has piechart()/piechart2() and "static/data"/"static/data2"

```
function piechart() {
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(["#0600f3","#f30000","#00b109"]);

var pie = d3.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

var path = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 10)
    .innerRadius(0);

var label = d3.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius - 40)
    .innerRadius(radius - 40);

d3.csv("static/data.csv?x="+new Date().getTime(), function(d) {
  d.population = +d.population;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var arc = g.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

  arc.append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.population); });

  arc.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + label.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.population ; });

});


}
```

I'm adding the pie charts to the script by calling the javascript functions:

```
<script>piechart()</script>
<script>piechart2()</script>
```

Thoughts? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that both your `js` files are trying to append the pie charts to the same `svg` element area in your html document. So essentially you have 2 functions trying to draw 2 different pie charts in the same area.

One way to avoid this is to have 2 `svg` elements and give them `ids`. This way you can make your DOM selections based on id. So you can try something like this:

```
<div class="row">
     <h3 align="center" >Connect</h3>
      <div class="row placeholders">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2">
          <svg width="300" height="200" id="svg1"></svg>
          <svg width="300" height="200" id="svg2"></svg>
          <script>piechart()</script>
          <script>piechart2()</script>
        </div>
</div>
```

And then when you have to select the area for drawing the graph, you can chose `d3.select("#svg1")` in your first file and `d3.select("#svg2")` in your second file.

Comment: Hmm... I've made the changes that you suggested, but it looks like I'm getting the same result. I see one pie chart and when I go to designer tools I see the second svg (svg#svg2), but no graphic.